# can't figure what might causing this error when creating PDO object

Tags: php, pdo

i am following a tutorial to create an OOP based login system.I did everything accordingly but while creating pdo i am getting an error in DB.php file in line 15.Can't figure out the reason for this error.Been stuck there for some time.Can anyone help me out with this error .The code might look long but it is a piece of cake for you i promise.There are FOUR php files.

1.init.php file holds the ingredients to create a new PDO() object.

2.config.php file is used to get data from init.php file as string is passed to it as ('mysql/host') type and use explode() function to extract data from it.

2.DB.php file is used to connect to database.
The error i am getting is

[image]

DB.php file:

```
class DB{
    private $_instance=null;
    private $pdo,
            $query,
            $error=false,
            $results,
            $count=0;
    private function __construct(){
            try{

                $this->$pdo=new PDO('mysql:host='.Config::get('mysql/host').';dbname='.Config::get('mysql/db'),Config::get('mysql/user'),Config::get('mysql/password'));


            }catch(PDOException as $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
    }
    public static function getInstance(){
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
              self::$_instance=new DB();
        }

            return self::$_instance;
        }

    }
```

Config.php file:

```
 class Config{

        public static function get($path){
           if($path){
                $config=$GLOBALS['config'];
                $arr=explode('/',$path);
                foreach($arr as $bit){
                    if(isset($config[$bit])){

                        $config=$config[$bit];

                    }
                }
                return $config;
            }
        }
    }
```

init.php file:

```
session_start();

$GLOBALS['config']=array(
    'mysql'=>array(

        'host' => 'localhost',
        'db' => 'login',
        'user' => 'root',
        'password' => ''

    )

);

spl_autoload_register(function($class){

    require_once 'c:/xampp/htdocs/login/classes/'.$class.'.php';

});

require_once 'c:/xampp/htdocs/login/function/sanitize.php';
```

index.php file:

```
   require_once 'c:/xampp/htdocs/login/core/init.php'; 

  DB::getInstance()->query('SELECT name FROM table WHERE id=1');
```

Comment: `catch(PDOException as $e)` -> `catch(PDOException $e)` Why do you use an `as` ?! makes no sense here (For more information see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: Remove the `as`. This isn't an alias.

Comment: One of these days I'm going to have an alias of my very own @Fred-ii-

Comment: You already have one *Sam* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: Ah! So I do *Ralph*! @Fred-ii- and back to the coffee pot I go!

Comment: ...and I to the "melting pot" *Sam!* @JayBlanchard

Comment: I take it that, removing the `as` didn't do anything; *correct?*. So, where are we at here; my dog's waiting for me to take him outside and run after Lord knows what.

Comment: good to see that you people are having fun :p !!Thanks anyway

Comment: Oh, there you are @AL-zami welcome back. Did you get us all a nice cup of coffee? You might have just came back from the *bistro* somewhere ;-) A nice apple danish would have been sweet.

Comment: @AL-zami I don't want to stand longer in the rain, so can you please tell me if removing the `as` from the catch header solved your problem?!

Comment: opps,late reply.Sorry to keep you standing alone in the rain ,in case you didn't notice i've already thanked everyone  ;p @Rizier123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message is a Parse Error.  This means the PHP interpreter/processor/program tried to read your file, but found a syntax error, and had to stop.  If you look at Line 15 of DB.php (per the error message)

```
}catch(PDOException as $e){
```

You'll see the problem.  This isn't valid PHP syntax -- you probably want

```
}catch(PDOException $e){
```

The `PDOException` bit of that is a a class type hint for the exception handling code -- there's no need to use the `as`.

Comment: OP wasn't responding to any of our comments, so maybe they'll listen to you ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ha, I didn't notice that up there.  My general internet policy is to ignore the comments :)

Comment: i checked all the sweet comments you people left in the comment section.No wonder why ants suddenly attacked my monitor ;p

Comment: @AlanStorm  oh ! thanks for your valuable answer..it added two more valuable reputation to my profile ;)